# angularJS remove animation, "duplicate" item during animation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, css-animations, ng-animate

I'm new in AngularJS and I would like to have animation when an item in my `ng-repeat` is deleted.

I managed to make the animation without problems but I have a little problem though.

During the animation, we can see another "item" behind the one which disappears.
in the attached screenshot, I highlight the block which disappears and, we see another block:

[image]

I'm using this CSS :

```
.rule-list {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.6s, background-color 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.6s, background-color 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.6s, background-color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.6s, background-color 0.3s;
    opacity:1;
}
.rule-list.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
    -moz-animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
    animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
  }

.rule-list.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation: fadeOutLeftBig 1s;
    -moz-animation: fadeOutLeftBig 1s;
    -ms-animation: fadeOutLeftBig 1s;
    animation: fadeOutLeftBig 1s;
}
```

my template :

```
<div ng-repeat="rule in rules" class="panel panel-default rule-list" >
    <!-- Rule 1 -->
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-btns">
            <a class="minimize" href="">−</a>
        </div>
        <h4 class="panel-title">{{rule.name}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="display: block;">
        <p>
            If <strong>{{rule.condition}}</strong> includes <strong>"{{rule.text}}"</strong>
            then <strong>{{rule.action}}</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a class="text-danger" ng-click="remove($index)">Delete Rule</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- panel-body -->

</div>
```

and my controller

```
    .controller('RulesController', function($scope, $stateParams) {

    $scope.rules = [
        {
            "name": "Rule 1",
            "condition": "email to",
            "text": "@***.com",
            "action": "exclude email"
        },
        {
            "name": "Rule 2",
            "condition": "email from",
            "text": "@***.fr",
            "action": "exclude email"
        },
        {
            "name": "Rule 3",
            "condition": "email from & to",
            "text": "@***.eu",
            "action": "exclude email"
        },
        {
            "name": "Rule 4",
            "condition": "email from & to",
            "text": "****",
            "action": "exclude email"
        },
    ];
        $scope.remove = function(index){
            console.log('remove '+index)
            $scope.rules.splice(index, 1);

        }

    })
```

Comment: AngularJS version? Using `animate.css`? Browser?

Comment: Angular 1.3.9. i'm using `animate.css` and I tested on chrome

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem. Here is my try: http://plnkr.co/edit/GPALgUZZSi2XqPzKxMEz?p=info

Comment: Any other CSS involved that might cause it?

Comment: Hmm, I use Bootstrap too. 
Nothing special other than that.

Comment: Used that in my Plunker too.

Comment: I haven't my code here, I'll watch this tomorrow.
Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: Ok, The problem was only in Chrome and in my app, (not in your plunker).
I should not have a good version of `animate.css`
Taking the same version as on your plunker, everything works fine.
However I took the animate.css this site:
[link](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: No problem, glad you could solve it :)